# Android ListView in widget onClick not working

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview, remoteview, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to make the listrows in my ListView Widget clickable by using the `setOnClickFillInIntent` method but whenever I click a ListItem nothing happends. Here are some key parts of my code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle extras = new Bundle();

extras.putInt(Resource.WIDGET_PACKAGE, position);
i.putExtras(extras);
row.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_layout_parent, i);
```

This is at the end of `getView()` in my ViewFactory. Resource.WIDGET_PACKAGE contains my package name and is just like any other key. The position int is from the `getView()` parameters. `R.id.widget_layout_parent` is the parent layout in all of the list items.

Here's the end of my WidgetProviders `onUpdate()`

```
Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, ItemListActivity.class);

PendingIntent clickPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_layout_parent, clickPI);

appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds[i],
        R.id.widget_list_view);
```

Is there something I'm missing or is there anything else you'd like to know?

All help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you call `setPendingIntentTemplate(...)`, the `id` should be that of the AdapterView (in this case the ListView). When you call `setOnClickFillInIntent(...)`, the `id` should be that of the root View of the item layout, whcih is what you are already doing if I read your original post correctly.

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager manager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    /* ... */
    widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.appwidget_listview, clickPI);
    /* ... */
}

public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    /* ... */
    row.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_layout_parent, intent);
    /* ... */
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer!
After hours of researching, this was the exact answer I was looking for.

Comment: Do anyone have full code example of listview onclick in android widget? I followed https://laaptu.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/android-app-widget-with-listview/ example, but there are no item onclick. I tried to add onclick but it's not working. :(

Comment: @MostafaImran this is covered in detail here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#implementing_collections. If you have a specific problem, open a new question and provide enough code and information so that we can help.

Answer (score 6):

If your app is targeting Android 12 and above, you might need to update from `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE`

Note that `FLAG_MUTABLE` is important, otherwise the fill-in intent from View Factory won't be updated into the pending intent template.

```kotlin
val flag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
} else {
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
}
val clickPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clickIntent, flag)
```

Answer (score 4):

Above answer by @karakuri works perfect.

Both setPendingIntentTemplate and setOnClickFillInIntent must be used together. One won't work without the other.